# What do the colors of output in rails console and Rails server log mean?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rails-console

I'm running `rails server` and `rails console` in Ubuntu 14.04 inside the generic terminal (app is just called "Terminal").

Whenever I run commands that involve the database, the console outputs which SQL query it sent but sometimes the text a turquoise color and sometimes it's a purple color. For example in this console output:

```
2.2.2 :025 >   pl = ProjectLevel.find_by(name: 'Premium')

ProjectLevel Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "project_levels".* FROM "project_levels" WHERE "project_levels"."deleted_at" 
IS NULL AND "project_levels"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Premium"]]

=> #<ProjectLevel id: 1, name: "Premium", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2015-07-15 15:45:40", updated_at: "2015-07-15 15:45:40">
```

(The colors that show up on here are not the same as my console)

The part that says `ProjectLevel Load (0.5ms)` will sometimes be turqoise but will sometimes be purple but every other part of the text is. Does this color actually mean anything? Is it telling me something about the success of the query or the data returned? Usually things like this in Rails are pretty intuitive (like when a test suite returns green text vs red text to tell you if the tests were successful) but  I can't seem to find anything about where those colors are coming from

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Rails 5, the colors indicate the type of query:

- Blue for selects

  [image]
- Yellow for updates

  [image]
- Green for inserts

  [image]
- Red for deletes

  [image]

In addition to various other colors for things like `alter table` or `begin`/`commit` statements.

---

Prior to Rails 5, the colors don't mean anything. They just alternate back and forth so you can easily tell where one query stops and the next query begins.

`10.times { Photo.all }` yields:

[image]

Comment: That seems counter-intuitive to me. This whole time, I was thinking that the purple ones meant that the query failed (I didn't have enough right next to each other to see that the colors just alternated). But at least now I know!

Comment: Is there a way to customize the colors?

Comment: Nevermind, I've found it, just edit ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb and edit the color and restart the server.

Comment: @jedi Late response, but that's a bad idea. You shouldn't edit your installed gems, ever! The changes will not follow your project around (every other installation will get the *real* gem from rubygems.org), and they'll be lost if you ever upgrade the gem.

Comment: what does the `load (0.5ms)` mean here?

Comment: @hiveer It's the amount of time the query took to execute.